# An ordinal is well-ordered by inclusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Recall that we define $\alpha < \beta$ if $\alpha \in \beta$ and $\alpha \leq \beta$ if $\alpha \in \beta$ or $\alpha = \beta$. Prove that for ordinals $\alpha, \beta$,
$\alpha \leq \beta$ iff $\alpha \subseteq \beta$.

(===>) If $\alpha < \beta$, then $\alpha \in \beta$ and so $\alpha \subseteq \beta$ as $\beta$ is trnasitive.

What about the other direction.?

Comment: If $\alpha =\beta$, meh. If $\alpha \subset\beta$, then $\alpha$ is a proper [order ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(order_theory)). Therefore, there exists $x\in \beta$ such that $\alpha =\{z\in \beta \colon z\in x\}$. However $\color{grey}{\alpha =}\{z\in \beta \colon z\in x\}=x$. It follows that $\alpha \in \beta$.

Comment: @Git Gud, cannot be done without using the oder ideal notion?

Comment: You already have the order ideal concept for sure, just maybe without a name or with a different one.

Comment: Mark, you don’t need the notion of an order ideal; in this context saying that $\alpha$ is an order ideal just says that $\alpha$ is an initial segment of $\beta$, so that if $\xi<\eta\in\alpha$, then $\xi\in\alpha$. If $\alpha\subsetneqq\beta$, then $\beta\setminus\alpha\ne\varnothing$; let $x=\min(\beta\setminus\alpha$ and proceed as in Git Gud’s comment.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Given ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $\alpha \subsetneq \beta$, what can we say about the least element of $\beta \setminus \alpha$?

Comment: Cannot we just prove it by the fact that either $\alpha \in \beta$ or $\beta \in \alpha$ and since $\alpha$ is a proper subset so the first one must holds.

Comment: @Mark If you can use the fact that for all ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we have $\alpha \in \beta$, $\alpha = \beta$, or $\beta \in \alpha$, then indeed this would make the exercise easy, as you point out.  I was assuming that you hadn't proved this fact yet, because it is harder than the exercise and often, the exercise is used in the proof of this fact.